# Many-to-Many Relation - Select all A except for those linked to B

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship between items `A` and `B` in my database

```
     A                B               A_B_Join
============     ============     ===============
 Id  |  ...       Id  |  ...       A_Id  |  B_Id
------------     ------------     ---------------
  0  |  ...        5  |  ...          0  |  5
  1  |  ...        6  |  ...          0  |  7
  2  |  ...        7  |  ...          1  |  5
  3  |  ...        8  |  ...          1  |  6
                                      2  |  6
     :                :               2  |  7
     :                :               3  |  7
                                      3  |  8
                                      3  |  5
```

I am trying to get for example, all `A`s that don't have a corresponding value of `B` from an arbitrary list, say, `[7, 8]`

What I have so far that is incorrect is:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A INNER JOIN A_B_Join ON A.id=A_B_Join.A_id WHERE A_B_Join.B_Id NOT IN (:BIds)
```

where `BIds` is my list `[7, 8]`. However this isn't exactly correct since it will still select those specific `A` rows which don't a corresponding `B_id` value specified in `BIds`

I have tried searching for examples and solutions for problems similar to mine but I'm not sure what this type of `Query` is called. I would appreciate any help with this or pointers to any duplicate questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`. The *inner* query will get all `A`s that has `7` or `8` but since `NOT EXISTS` was use, it will display all rows from `A` that is not present in the inner query.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM A_B_Join b
                    WHERE a.ID = b.A_ID
                            AND b.B_ID IN (7, 8))
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses a left anti-join:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN A_B_Join j
    ON a.id = j.A_Id AND j.B_Id IN (7, 8)
WHERE
    j.A_Id IS NULL;
```

Note that this will include *all* `A` records which do not match to a `B_Id` in (7, 8).  This would includes `A` records which in fact do not join to anything at all in the junction table.  We could change this logic to include only matches not in (7, 8) if you require it.

Comment: Thank you, how would the efficiency of this query differ from @John Woo's response? It seems that he is using some type of nested query?

Comment: @sshashank124 First let me know if this query works for you.  Then I will comment on efficiency.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to run it, but I've read it over and it seems to be exactly what i want

Comment: Using `WHERE EXISTS` can be faster than a join, but if you have indices setup on the join columns in my query, then either approach should be acceptable to you.

Comment: I do have indices set up on both columns in A_B_Join

Comment: I have always found joins and anti-joins to be very intuitive, so I use them often.  You may try both answers and see which works best for you.

Comment: @sshashank124 this always depends on how you structured your schema. a lot of articles online can be found about efficiency (example [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS VS LEFT JOIN](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)) but it  always better to test with your set of data in your selected RDBMS.

Comment: I don't believe the size of the data in my application will ever approach the case where a difference between these two methods would make an impact. I will go with the `NOT EXISTS` implementation for now but thank you both for the two approaches